# Need help in URL rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

The URL rewrite condition is always taking me to the index file, i dont know why, below is my case.

my link is:
http://www.anabrokers.com/contents_12/Selling%20Your%20Business

my htaccsess contains the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} contents_
RewriteRule    ^(.*)$    /Home/contents.php/?$     [NC,L]
```

Tips:
Hosted on Godaddy
PHP version 5.3.24

Comment: Try to add start of string too `^contents_` instead.

Comment: Didn't work, thank you.